# use a loop instead of manually repeating each line and changing the number

Tags: jquery, loops

I have all these numbered ids 1 - 9 and `ul` ids 1 - 17 in odds 1, 3, 5 etc.

I know I can use a loop here instead of manually repeating each line and changing the number, can someone help me get started on how to code the jQuery?

```
$("div.text-right#top-1").append(vwo_$("ul#ul-1 li:first-child"));
$("div.text-right#top-2").append(vwo_$("ul#ul-3 li:first-child"));
$("div.text-right#top-3").append(vwo_$("ul#ul-5 li:first-child"));
$("div.text-right#top-4").append(vwo_$("ul#ul-7 li:first-child"));
$("div.text-right#top-5").append(vwo_$("ul#ul-9 li:first-child"));
$("div.text-right#top-6").append(vwo_$("ul#ul-11 li:first-child"));
$("div.text-right#top-7").append(vwo_$("ul#ul-13 li:first-child"));
$("div.text-right#top-8").append(vwo_$("ul#ul-15 li:first-child"));
$("div.text-right#top-9").append(vwo_$("ul#ul-17 li:first-child"));
```

Comment: use `i` on the first and `i * 2 -1` on the second

Comment: You could definitely use a loop to do this, but using DOM traversal would be better as it's more robust and easier to maintain. If you could add a sample of yout HTML to the question I can give you an example of how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a simple `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    $("div.text-right#top-" + i).append($("ul#ul-" + (i*2-1) + " li:first-child"));
}
```